# How i can use the handleSubmit inside my component?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, formik

I'm making input validations with `formik`, when my form is filled he calls the function `handleSubmit`, but this function is outside my hook component, so I can't call `dispatchs`.

**How I can put the `handleSubmit` logic inside my hook component?**

This is my code:

```
const schema = Yup.object().shape({
  email: Yup.string().email('Email don't have a valid format').required('Fill the email!'),
  password: Yup.string().required('Fill the password')
})

const enhanceWithFormik = withFormik({
  mapPropsToValues: () => 
  ({ 
      email: '', password: ''
  }),
  handleSubmit: values => {
    registerFirstData(values)
  },
  validateOnMount: false,
  validateOnChange: true,
  validateOnBlur: true,
  displayName: 'RegistrarForm',
  validationSchema: schema
})

const Register = props => {

const {
  values,
  touched,
  errors,
  isSubmitting,
  handleChange,
  handleBlur,
  handleSubmit
} = props;

return (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className={classes.form} noValidate>
   ...
  </form>
)
}

export default enhanceWithFormik(Register);
```

What i tried:

```
const Register = props => {

    const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();

    const handleSubmit = values => {
      console.log(values)
    }

     const {
        values,
        touched,
        errors,
        isSubmitting,
        handleChange,
        handleBlur,
        // Removed handleSubmit from here
    } = props;

    return (
         <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className={classes.form} noValidate>
    ...
    )
```

But this way my page is reloaded when i click in my submit button

Comment: You can use Form element from formik and onSubmit will fire after you click on button with type submit

Comment: @demkovych i try this way, can u check my edit?

Comment: `inside my hook component` what is your `hook component`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How I can put the handleSubmit logic inside

It's very simple, don't use `withFormik` and use the `Formik` component.

```
const schema = Yup.object().shape({
    email: Yup.string().email('Email don\'t have a valid format').required('Fill the email!'),
    password: Yup.string().required('Fill the password')
})

const Register = props => {

    const onSubmit = values => {
        // Do what you want
        // Here you can call dispatch with the form values
        console.log(values)
    }

    return (
        <Formik
            initialValues={{
                email: '', password: ''
            }}
            validateOnMount={false}
            displayName='RegistrarForm'
            validationSchema={schema}
            onSubmit={onSubmit}
        >
            {({ values, touched, errors, isSubmitting, handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit }) => (
                <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className={classes.form} noValidate>
                    {/* ... */}
                </Form>
            )}
        </Formik>
    )
}

export default Register;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure I understood your question correctly. Here's what I understood: You want to dispatch a Redux action when the form is submitted but can't do that, so you put a submit handler into the component (additionaly to the one in `withFormik`) and the result is that the page reloads on submit.

A couple things:

- If you override the submit handler inside your component and pass that to the `Form`, the default implementation of Formik (which contains your submit handler from `withFormik`) does not apply any longer. Note that a submit handler takes an event (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onsubmit), not the values as you suggest in your custom submit handler inside the component. As you then do not call `event.preventDefault()` in your custom submit handler, the page is reloaded, as this is the default behavior for form submission.
- Actually you should be able to dispatch a Redux action inside the `withFormik` definition. If you check out the Formik docs, `handleSubmit` is called with two parameters, `values` and `actions`. Next to the so called Formik helpers, `actions` contains the props of the enhanced component. Therefore, if you connect your component to the redux store and inside `mapDispatchToProps` pass in a prop like `dispatchMyAction`, you should be able to dispatch an action inside `withFormik`'s `handleSubmit` function by calling `actions.props.dispatchMyAction`.

So I'd try something like this:

```
...

const enhanceWithFormik = withFormik({
  handleSubmit: (values, actions) => {
    registerFirstData(values)
    actions.props.dispatchMyAction()
  },
  ...
})

const Register = props => {
  return (
    <Form className={classes.form} noValidate>
      ...
    </Form>
  )
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    dispatchMyAction: () => dispatch(myActionCreator())
  }
}

export default enhanceWithFormik(connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Register));
```

Of course I can't try if this solves your problem as you did't provide a MVE...